# placement issue with iPython Notebook sever widgets

Tags: widget, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I am not able to understand why a particular piece of code doesn't work the way I want it to work. Here is a simple set of widgets for the iPython Notebook server.

```
from IPython.html import widgets # Widget definitions
from IPython.display import display # Used to display widgets in the notebook

def returnParameter(parameterName = 'Specify Name'):
    parameter = [ widgets.CheckboxWidget(), 
                  widgets.TextWidget(value=parameterName),
                  widgets.DropdownWidget(values=['A', 'B']),            ]

    h_container = widgets.ContainerWidget(children=parameter)
    return h_container

v_container = widgets.ContainerWidget( children=[ returnParameter(str(i)) for i in range(10) ] )

display(v_container) # <<- here it works

for h in v_container.children:
    h.remove_class('vbox')
    h.add_class('hbox')

# display(v_container) # <<- moving it here does not change 'hbox'
```

For some reason, the property of `h_container` within the `returnParameter()` function does not change if I do a `display(v_container)` *after* the point at which I do change the parameter. However, it does seem to change if I place this line *before*. I am not certain why this is. Any help? I would ideally want to push the property changes within the function `returnParameter()` but for the reason stated above, this apparently is not possible. Any suggestions?

Comment: What version of IPython are you on? If you can reproduce that with IPython master, please file a bug so we can look into it.

Comment: Hi! I am using iPython 2.3.1. I am not sure what master is, but I will look into it. Thank you.